# Manually Set Dirty Flag for QUndoStack

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a project that has an incomplete implementation of QUndoStack, and I need a way to make sure the dirty flag is set even if something happens that isn't covered by our Undo/Redo implementation. Unfortunately, it seems that the QUndoStack only gives a setClean function. Is there an easy way to get this in until we finish the Undo/Redo?

Comment: If you have a custom implementation, what does it have to do with QUS?

Comment: By "incomplete implementation" I meant that it doesn't cover the entire stack. I ended up just manually setting my own dirty flag which is partially controlled by the QUS clean flag.